# SQL Insert null if missing keys/values of reading dictionary using python

Tags: python, sql, json, dictionary, mariadb

From a list of dictionary...with missing keys
The list of dict as follows

```
[{"log_number":"1","timestamp":"2020-01-11 04:23:31","staff_id":"A123","staff_name":"Krill","staff_department":"Sales","service_id":"11111","service_number":"BU-11111","description":"This is description1"},{"log_number":"2","timestamp":"2020-01-11 07:03:39","staff_id":"A456","staff_name":"James","staff_department":"Graphic","service_id":"22222","service_number":"XU-22211","state":"AAA","city":"AAA"},{"log_number":"3","timestamp":"2020-01-27 14:29:11","temp_staff_id":"A571","temp_staff_name":"Mary","staff_department":"Engr","service_id":"89000","service_number":"SP-89001","state":"BBB","city":"BBB"},{"log_number":"4","timestamp":"2020-01-27 15:08:20","staff_id":"A765","staff_name":"Alex","staff_department":"Sales","service_id":"09880","service_number":"XU-09880","description":"This is description3333"}]

I have follow some suggestions here but yet to resolve the issue.

**method1:**

    sql = "INSERT INTO `table1` (`log_number`, `timestamp`, `staff_id`, `staff_name`, `temp_staff_id`, `temp_staff_name`, `staff_department`, `service_id`, `service_number`, `state`, `city`, `description`, `additional_remarks`) VALUES ( %(log_number)s, %(timestamp)s, %(staff_id)s, %(staff_name)s, %(temp_staff_id)s, %(temp_staff_name)s, %(staff_department)s, %(service_id)s, %(service_number)s, %(state)s, %(city)s, %(description)s, %(additional_remarks)s )"
    cursor.executemany( sql, mydata['response']['client_log']['data'])

    **error return**
    1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; c....


**method2:**

    sql_template = 'INSERT INTO `table1` ({}) VALUES ({})'
    sql_inserts = []

    for row in mydata['response']['client_log']['data']:
        sql_keys = row.keys()
        sql_values = []

        for key in sql_keys:
            sql_values.append(row[key])

               sql_inserts.append(sql_template.format(', '.join(sql_keys), ', '.join(sql_values)))

    for insert in sql_inserts:
        cursor.executemany(insert, mydata['response']['client_log']['data'])

    **error return**
    1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; ...
```

I believed this is due to the missing keys and differences of keys on each dict. Please help me how to resolve it. Thank you for you kindness and attention.

@@@@@#######@@@@@@

To check missing keys in each dict, if not exists add with value None

```
for entry in data['response']['client_log']['data']:
    if "state" not in entry:
        entry["state"] = None
    if "city" not in entry:
        entry["city"] = None
    if "description" not in entry:
        entry["description"] = None
    if "additional_remarks" not in entry:
        entry["additional_remarks"] = None
    else:
        continue
print(data)
```

Other than use if-else (it can be long) any other method to achieve the same result above?
Updated thanks to @MatBailie

Comment: Are -all- of those dictionary entries optional?  Or are some (for example; log number and timestamp) mandatory?

Comment: Method 1, using execute many, needs you to supply NULL values to the missing keys.  That's what I would do.  Iterate through your dictionaries (or a copy of the whole array of dictionaries), then for each dictionary iterate through the -full- list of fields/keys, and add any missing keys with a value of `None`.

Comment: Method 2 is failing because you're using string substitution to add your values to the insert statement.  Never ever ever ever (ever) do that.  Always use the parameteristation you demonstrated in method 1.  (You could use Method2 to make a new sql statement for each dictionary, with different parameters to reflect the different keys in each dictionary, but then I expect you can't use ExecuteMany)

Comment: @ MatBailie some are mandatory...at least got 4 common parameters...fr example timestamp, lognumber, service id, servic number...

Comment: how can I supply null to the missing keys? do you have sample to do it? Im not too sure ...

Comment: Have you tried adding the missing keys to each dictionary, with the value being `None`?

Comment: adding manually and run the code? If all the keys on each dict exists and same as parameters in sql table, the code method1 works without any error and data inserted onto db. I have tested it.... Just when the parameter of each dict different or missing I got the problem as above stated...Im sorry sir, Im beginner in this area..hope you can show me the right way of doing it. Really need help. Thank you.

Comment: As per the second comment above:  Iterate through your dictionaries (or a copy of the whole array of dictionaries), then for each dictionary iterate through the -full- list of fields/keys, and add any missing keys with a value of `None`.  *(Write a loop in Python to fill in the missing entries...)*

Comment: Hi sir, can you provde some sample based on my scenario on how it can be done...appreciate it, thank you

Comment: I update as above to check missing key...

Comment: Don't use `elif`? Just use `if`? So that every check is made, rather than stopping at the first missing key?

Comment: Have you tried setting a ```DEFAULT``` value of ```NULL``` on the relevant database columns?

Comment: Hi..default is already null, it does not work....